# objective-c create and compare time - running from different countries

Tags: objective-c, time

I have an app that is used in different countries.  In my app I am performing a simple calculation that states if the current time is later than 3pm, do something.

This is how I am creating the 3pm.

```
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *dateAttempt = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateAttempt setYear:2016];
    [dateAttempt setMonth:05];
    [dateAttempt setDay:18];
    [dateAttempt setHour:15];
    [dateAttempt setMinute:00];
    NSDate *threePm = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateAttempt];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateAttempt);
    NSLog(@"%@", threePm);
```

I am creating the app in NewYork.  When I run the above code I get...
2016-05-18 11:17:53.815 x[1312:37272] 2016-05-18 19:00:00 +0000

I guess that makes sense because NewYork is 4 hours behind UTC. (it's 11am at the time of me writing this)

So the threePm is giving me the UTC equivalent of 3pm in NY, and its working as expected.  The problem is when I change the time on the laptop simulator to simulate being in another country.  For example Greece.
If I switch the time on the pc to greece, the same code above gives a different result due to a different time adjustment to UTC.

How can I say... no matter where in the world the app is running, if time is later than 3pm (EST)... do something?

Comment: Try `currentCalendar`, `autoupdatingCurrentCalendar` or setting `timeZone` of `calendar`.

Comment: adding timezone worked... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate` stores absolute time - actually the time offset from a fixed point in UTC time.

`NSDateComponents` has a `timeZone` property which is used as the basis for the conversion to `NSDate`, and this will default to the current timezone - as your results show.

If you always want 3pm in New York set this property. New York is one of the standard time zones: America/New_York; so you can set this property using:

```
dateAttempt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
```

An `NSTimeZone` understands daylight savings and dependent on the date you set the conversion will translate from EST or EDT as appropriate.

HTH